# How to create table with labels (first row and first column)

Tags: tables

Here is what I want:

[image]

And I created simple table as below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|cccccc}
     & 0.1    &  0.25   & 0.40    & 0.55    & 0.7     & 0.95   \\ \hline
  7  & 0.0052 &  \boxed{0.0031} &  0.0070 &  0.0075 &  0.0092 &  0.0048 \\
  8  & 0.0061 &  0.0075 &  0.0071 &  0.0065 &  0.0062 &  0.0078 \\
  9  & 0.0078 &  0.0087 &  0.0057 &  0.0079 &  0.0094 &  0.0060 \\
  10 & 0.0040 &  0.0061 &  0.0084 &  0.0062 &  0.0060 &  0.0053 \\
  11 & 0.0075 &  0.0056 &  0.0056 &  0.0056 &  0.0066 &  0.0097 \\
  12 & 0.0054 &  \boxed{0.0030} &  0.0088 &  0.0085 &  0.0056 &  0.0091 \\
  13 & 0.0077 &  0.0073 &  0.0059 &  0.0075 &  0.0049 &  0.0053 \\
  14 & 0.0062 &  0.0057 &  0.0099 &  0.0068 &  0.0087 &  0.0067 \\
  15 & 0.0061 &  0.0069 &  0.0101 &  0.0065 &  0.0080 &  0.0071 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Can someone please help me understand how can I put labels on first row and first column like show in image? Any help, links or resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, complete your code snipped to small documment, which can be compiled. Also what you mean with "labels"? Frames around some cells?

Comment: For the upper text (Learning rate) try adding the line ` & & & & Learning rate & & & \\ ` as a first line inside the tabular environment.

Comment: @Zarko he meant by label the side and upper text from what i understand, since his code doesn't containt the two texts.

Comment: Can you tell is you are using a special document class rather than the usual class like article? and maybe also what font size?

Comment: @SAM I'm just using article class.

Comment: default font size or changed as an option ?

Comment: @SAM default font size

Comment: Can i know why do you ask with a profile and you comment with another profile which has the same name ?

Comment: well, I oversleep all :-)

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, readers *strongly dislike* to have to crane their necks to read a column header that's been rotated 90 degrees, especially if there's just a single such column header. I therefore recommend you place the string "Number of Neurons in Hidden Layer" above the first column, while providing one line break in the string. Separately, I would also recommend that you dispense with all vertical lines in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \boxed and \smash[b] macros
\usepackage{booktabs}% for \midrule and \cmidrule macros
\newcommand\headercell[1]{%
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{7}{c} @{}}
\headercell{Number of Neurons\\in Hidden Layer} & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{Learning Rate}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
& 0.1 &  0.25 & 0.40 & 0.55 & 0.7 & 0.95   \\ 
\midrule
  7  & 0.0052 &  \boxed{0.0031} &  0.0070 &  0.0075 &  0.0092 &  0.0048 \\
  8  & 0.0061 &  0.0075 &  0.0071 &  0.0065 &  0.0062 &  0.0078 \\
  9  & 0.0078 &  0.0087 &  0.0057 &  0.0079 &  0.0094 &  0.0060 \\
  10 & 0.0040 &  0.0061 &  0.0084 &  0.0062 &  0.0060 &  0.0053 \\
  11 & 0.0075 &  0.0056 &  0.0056 &  0.0056 &  0.0066 &  0.0097 \\
  12 & 0.0054 &  \boxed{0.0030} &  0.0088 &  0.0085 &  0.0056 &  0.0091 \\
  13 & 0.0077 &  0.0073 &  0.0059 &  0.0075 &  0.0049 &  0.0053 \\
  14 & 0.0062 &  0.0057 &  0.0099 &  0.0068 &  0.0087 &  0.0067 \\
  15 & 0.0061 &  0.0069 &  0.0101 &  0.0065 &  0.0080 &  0.0071 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks very nice.   Would you mind providing a bit of walk through to the interesting pieces that you've added?   In particular, what are `@{}`, `@c{}`, and `*{7}{c}` doing?  And could you motivate the definition of headercell (the role of `smash`, etc.)?

Comment: @MikeWojnowicz - `*{7}{c}` is shorthand for `ccccccc`. `@{}` serves to suppress the whiespace padding that would otherwise be inserted to the left of the first column and to the right of the seventh column. `\multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{...}` instructs LaTeX to center the contents across 6 columns, while allowing for whitespace padding on the left but none on the right. The `\smash[b]` part in `\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{...} ... \end{tabular}}` is a bit of a trick, to make sure that the second row of the `tabular` environment is invisible to the other six columns and hence doesn't ... (continued)

Comment: @MikeWojnowicz -- (continued) ... interfere with or otherwise affect the optimal placement of the rule across the six columns or the header cells in the next row. TeX features a low-level command called `\smash` that sets the height and depth of its argument to zero. `\smash[b]` is an extension provided by the `amsmath` package, to set depth of the argument to zero while not affecting the height calculation. I recommend studying the user guide of the `amsmath` package for more information about `\smash` and `\smash[b]`.

Answer (score 2):

I used `\multicolumn` from the package `multirow` to merge the first tow columns together and the remaning columns of the first row together (where "Learning Rate" is contained). The other text must be rotated for that i used the command `\rotatebox` from the package `rotating`, and lay out on 9 rows (`\multirow`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{5pt}c|cccccc}
\multicolumn{2}{}{} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Learning Rate} \\
     & & 0.1    &  0.25   & 0.40    & 0.55    & 0.7     & 0.95   \\ \cline{2-8}
\multirow{9}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Number of Neurons in Hidden Layer}}
&  7  & 0.0052 &  \boxed{0.0031} &  0.0070 &  0.0075 &  0.0092 &  0.0048 \\
 & 8  & 0.0061 &  0.0075 &  0.0071 &  0.0065 &  0.0062 &  0.0078 \\
  & 9  & 0.0078 &  0.0087 &  0.0057 &  0.0079 &  0.0094 &  0.0060 \\
&   10 & 0.0040 &  0.0061 &  0.0084 &  0.0062 &  0.0060 &  0.0053 \\
  & 11 & 0.0075 &  0.0056 &  0.0056 &  0.0056 &  0.0066 &  0.0097 \\
&  12 & 0.0054 &  \boxed{0.0030} &  0.0088 &  0.0085 &  0.0056 &  0.0091 \\
&  13 & 0.0077 &  0.0073 &  0.0059 &  0.0075 &  0.0049 &  0.0053 \\
&  14 & 0.0062 &  0.0057 &  0.0099 &  0.0068 &  0.0087 &  0.0067 \\
&  15 & 0.0061 &  0.0069 &  0.0101 &  0.0065 &  0.0080 &  0.0071 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I get by rotating in the last row by 90 degrees around the bottom left corner a box containing the label for the rows; as I wished to keep the label for the rows as a one-liner that does not stick over the horizontal line, I decided to have TeX do some `\dimexpr`-calculations for spreading the `\hbox` with a negative value in case the line is too long under normal circumstances; the `\strut`s at the beginning and at the end of the label are there for ensuring that the box has enough depth which is important as rotation goes around a bottom corner:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength\MyScratchy
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.365}%
\settowidth\MyScratchy{0.0000}%
\newcommand*\nf[1]{{%
  \advance\fboxsep\fboxrule
  \fboxrule=0pt
  \fbox{\hbox to\MyScratchy{\hfil\ignorespaces#1\unskip\hfil}}%
}}%
\newcommand*\ff[1]{{%
  \fbox{\hbox to\MyScratchy{\hfil\ignorespaces#1\unskip\hfil}}%
}}%
\begin{tabular}{lr|*{6}{c}}%
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textsf{Learning Rate}}\\
&&0.1&0.25&0.40&0.55&0.7&0.95\\
\cline{2-8}%
&7&\nf{0.0052}&\ff{0.0031}&\nf{0.0070}&\nf{0.0075}&\nf{0.0092}&\nf{0.0048}\\
&8&\nf{0.0061}&\nf{0.0075}&\nf{0.0071}&\nf{0.0065}&\nf{0.0062}&\nf{0.0078}\\
&9&\nf{0.0078}&\nf{0.0087}&\nf{0.0057}&\nf{0.0079}&\nf{0.0094}&\nf{0.0060}\\
&10&\nf{0.0040}&\nf{0.0061}&\nf{0.0084}&\nf{0.0062}&\nf{0.0060}&\nf{0.0053}\\
&11&\nf{0.0075}&\nf{0.0056}&\nf{0.0056}&\nf{0.0056}&\nf{0.0066}&\nf{0.0097}\\
&12&\nf{0.0054}&\ff{0.0030}&\nf{0.0088}&\nf{0.0085}&\nf{0.0056}&\nf{0.0091}\\
&13&\nf{0.0077}&\nf{0.0073}&\nf{0.0059}&\nf{0.0075}&\nf{0.0049}&\nf{0.0053}\\
&14&\nf{0.0062}&\nf{0.0057}&\nf{0.0099}&\nf{0.0068}&\nf{0.0087}&\nf{0.0067}\\
\smash{%
  \lower\dimexpr\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname-\dp\strutbox+\arrayrulewidth\relax
  \hbox{\rotatebox[origin=bl]{90}{%
    \textsf{%
      %\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
      %\fbox{%
      \parbox[b]{\dimexpr 9\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+9\ht\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname\relax}{%
         \centering
         \begingroup
         \settowidth\MyScratchy{\hbox{Number of Neurons in Hidden Layer}}%
         \ifdim\MyScratchy>\dimexpr 9\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+9\ht\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname\relax
           \advance\MyScratchy-\dimexpr 9\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+9\ht\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname\relax
           \strut\hbox spread-\MyScratchy{Number of Neurons in Hidden Layer}\strut               
         \else
           \strut\hbox{Number of Neurons in Hidden Layer}\strut             
         \fi
         \endgroup
      }%
      %}%
    }%
  }}%
}%
&15&\nf{0.0061}&\nf{0.0069}&\nf{0.0101}&\nf{0.0065}&\nf{0.0080}&\nf{0.0071}\\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

(By the way: I used `\smash`for ensuring that height and depth of the rotated box won't affect the height of the table-row where the rotated box occurred.)

In case you wish a linebreak, I suggest omitting the spreading-calculations and letting the surrounding `\parbox` do its job while probably inserting some linebreak-commands oneself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength\MyScratchy
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.365}%
\settowidth\MyScratchy{0.0000}%
\newcommand*\nf[1]{{%
  \advance\fboxsep\fboxrule
  \fboxrule=0pt
  \fbox{\hbox to\MyScratchy{\hfil\ignorespaces#1\unskip\hfil}}%
}}%
\newcommand*\ff[1]{{%
  \fbox{\hbox to\MyScratchy{\hfil\ignorespaces#1\unskip\hfil}}%
}}%
\begin{tabular}{lr|*{6}{c}}%
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textsf{Learning Rate}}\\
&&0.1&0.25&0.40&0.55&0.7&0.95\\
\cline{2-8}%
&7&\nf{0.0052}&\ff{0.0031}&\nf{0.0070}&\nf{0.0075}&\nf{0.0092}&\nf{0.0048}\\
&8&\nf{0.0061}&\nf{0.0075}&\nf{0.0071}&\nf{0.0065}&\nf{0.0062}&\nf{0.0078}\\
&9&\nf{0.0078}&\nf{0.0087}&\nf{0.0057}&\nf{0.0079}&\nf{0.0094}&\nf{0.0060}\\
&10&\nf{0.0040}&\nf{0.0061}&\nf{0.0084}&\nf{0.0062}&\nf{0.0060}&\nf{0.0053}\\
&11&\nf{0.0075}&\nf{0.0056}&\nf{0.0056}&\nf{0.0056}&\nf{0.0066}&\nf{0.0097}\\
&12&\nf{0.0054}&\ff{0.0030}&\nf{0.0088}&\nf{0.0085}&\nf{0.0056}&\nf{0.0091}\\
&13&\nf{0.0077}&\nf{0.0073}&\nf{0.0059}&\nf{0.0075}&\nf{0.0049}&\nf{0.0053}\\
&14&\nf{0.0062}&\nf{0.0057}&\nf{0.0099}&\nf{0.0068}&\nf{0.0087}&\nf{0.0067}\\
\smash{%
  \lower\dimexpr\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname-\dp\strutbox+\arrayrulewidth\relax
  \hbox{\rotatebox[origin=bl]{90}{%
    \textsf{%
      %\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
      %\fbox{%
      \parbox[b]{\dimexpr 9\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+9\ht\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname\relax}{%
         \centering
         \strut Number of Neurons\linebreak in Hidden Layer\strut
      }%
      %}%
    }%
  }}%
}%
&15&\nf{0.0061}&\nf{0.0069}&\nf{0.0101}&\nf{0.0065}&\nf{0.0080}&\nf{0.0071}\\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
&& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Learning Rate}\\
&& 0.1    &  0.25   & 0.40    & 0.55    & 0.7     & 0.95   \\ \hline\\
\rotatebox{90}{\multirow{10}*{\vspace{96pt}\hspace{-150pt}Number of Neurons in Hidden Layer}}  & \vspace{5pt} 7  & 0.0052 & \boxed{0.0031} &  0.0070 &  0.0075 &  0.0092 &  0.0048 \\
& \vspace{5pt}8  & 0.0061 &  0.0075 &  0.0071 &  0.0065 &  0.0062 &  0.0078 \\
&\vspace{5pt}9  & 0.0078 &  0.0087 &  0.0057 &  0.0079 &  0.0094 &  0.0060 \\
&\vspace{5pt}10 & 0.0040 &  0.0061 &  0.0084 &  0.0062 &  0.0060 &  0.0053 \\
&\vspace{5pt}11 & 0.0075 &  0.0056 &  0.0056 &  0.0056 &  0.0066 &  0.0097 \\
&\vspace{5pt}12 & 0.0054 & \boxed{0.0030} &  0.0088 &  0.0085 &  0.0056 &  0.0091 \\
&\vspace{5pt}13 & 0.0077 &  0.0073 &  0.0059 &  0.0075 &  0.0049 &  0.0053 \\
&\vspace{5pt}14 & 0.0062 &  0.0057 &  0.0099 &  0.0068 &  0.0087 &  0.0067 \\
&\vspace{5pt}15 & 0.0061 &  0.0069 &  0.0101 &  0.0065 &  0.0080 &  0.0071 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: rottbl]