# What to put into the intersection of the row/column labels of a table?

Tags: tables, spacing, typography

I have a grid/table/matrix with separate [labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59517/80509) for the rows and the columns. However, I also want to label these labels themselves (by indicating the "type" of the labels, such as SI units, etc.)

Here is a MWE, with three variants (check the entry `abc/def` in the upper left position, describing the row labels `abc` and the column labels `def`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Forward slash.}
\[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
abc/def & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\
\end{array}\]
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Vertical bar.}
\[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
abc|def & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\
\end{array}\]
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Backslash.}
\[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
abc\backslash def & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\
\end{array}\]
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this MWE suffers from (at least) the following two problems: the first column (labelling the rows) is too wide, and the centered labels are far from the core of the array itself (right-aligning could help, but... that introduces other problems). Second, the spacing around abc/def looks incorrect.

The questions is, basically, how should I typeset this array nicely? What should I put to the upper left position, in place of `abc/def`? I do not wish to put `abc` and `def` into two distinct (multi)columns. Maybe stacking `abc` above (or under?) `def` is a start, but then I would still need some kind of visual separator (taking the role of the `\|/` symbols) within that cell. I should probably also clarify that both labels `abc` and `def` are in practice *very short*, typically I would write `x/y` or `n/m` or `n/k`, so single-character mathematical variables, and not lengthy texts.

---

Related: [How to create table with labels (first row and first column)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317874/how-to-create-table-with-labels-first-row-and-first-column)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/latex-table-cell-with-a-diagonal-line-and-2-sub-cells

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to suggest "none of the three possibilities". Instead, consider using a classic "tableau" setup, with a clear hierarchical structure in the header. Such a setup helps avoid creating the "cramped" look that's almost inevitable with any one of the three possibilities you've offered.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, and \cmidrule macros
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Still another approach}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}l*{5}{c}@{}}
\toprule
\text{abc} & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{\text{def}}\\
    \cmidrule(l){2-6}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\midrule
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I personally would probably center `abc` vertically to reduce the large white ocean right below it, but others might disagree with this. I also know that using vertical lines in table in general discouraged, and this proposal avoids them nicely.

Comment: @Matsmath - You're welcome. The idea behind placing the "abc" and "def" labels on the same row is to indicate that they're *hierarchically equal*. The material in the second header row is then easily seen as (a) being secondary and (b) belonging solely to "def".

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer (which I wrote more than 2 years ago) earlier today: Care to express what my answer provoked your displeasure? Don't be shy.

Answer (score 11):

Here are two options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,eqparbox}

\newcommand{\indices}[2]{{% \indices{<rows>}{<columns>}
  \begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
    \scriptstyle #2~\smash{\eqmakebox[ind]{$\scriptstyle\rightarrow$}} \\[-\jot]  
    \scriptstyle #1~\smash{\eqmakebox[ind]{$\scriptstyle\downarrow$}}
  \end{array}}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
    \indices{\text{abc}}{\text{def}}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & a & b & c & d & e \\
    2 & f & g & h & i & j \\
    3 & k & l & m & n & o
  \end{array}
\]

\[
  \begin{array}{cc|ccccc}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\text{def}} \\
    && 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \cline{2-7}
    & 1 & a & b & c & d & e \\
    \smash{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\text{abc}}} & 2 & f & g & h & i & j \\
    & 3 & k & l & m & n & o
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

If you're interested in a matrix-like command, there are some examples at [Where is the `\matrix` command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764). This includes using `\bordermatrix`, [`kbordermatrix`](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty) and [`blkarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray), all of which allows you to place indices to identify the rows/columns.

Answer (score 11):

It is also possible to use Ti*k*Z directly inside the tabular, needing no savebox at all to get the lenghts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Diagonal Split}
\[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\tikz{\node[below left, inner sep=1pt] (def) {def};%
      \node[above right,inner sep=1pt] (abc) {abc};%
      \draw (def.north west|-abc.north west) -- (def.south east-|abc.south east);}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\
\end{array}\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, inside the `\tikz` command you have the Ti*k*Z power to do whatever... Here is a version with repositioned nodes, a `very thin` `shorten`ed division line and fonts in `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Diagonal Split}
\[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\tikz[diag text/.style={inner sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize},
      shorten/.style={shorten <=#1,shorten >=#1}]{%
        \node[below left, diag text] (def) {def};
        \node[above right=2pt and -2pt, diag text] (abc) {abc};
        \draw[shorten=4pt, very thin] (def.north west|-abc.north west) -- (def.south east-|abc.south east);}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\
\end{array}\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

A tabular is used to create a minimal box containing the two labels.  Putting it into a savebox gives you the dimensions.  Finally, TikZ is used to draw a diagonal line from the upper left to lower right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}l@{\space}}
&abc\\def
\end{tabular}}

\begin{table}
\caption{Diagonal Split}
\[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\tikz[overlay]{\draw (0pt,\ht\tempbox) -- (\wd\tempbox,-\dp\tempbox);}%
\usebox{\tempbox}\hspace{\dimexpr 1pt-\tabcolsep}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\
\end{array}\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Do I lose antialiasing with this method?

Comment: If you go straight to PDF (pdflatex), no.  Otherwise, it depends on resolution of the medium.

Comment: You could use `diagbox` package for this kind of cell.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes I use diagonal lines or black boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newbox\MytempboxA
\newbox\MytempboxB
\newcommand\myTempA{}
\newcommand\myTempB{}
\newcommand\myTempC{}
\newcommand\myTempD{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}%
\caption{Diagonal line approach}%
\[%
\setbox\MytempboxA\hbox{\mbox{abc}}%
\setbox\MytempboxB\hbox{\mbox{def}}%
\begin{array}{@{}|r|*{5}{c}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{%
  \edef\myTempA{%
    \number\numexpr\dimexpr\wd\MytempboxA+2\arraycolsep\relax\relax
  }%
  \edef\myTempB{%
    \number
    \numexpr
      \dimexpr\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+%
              \ht\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+%
              \arrayrulewidth
      \relax
    \relax
  }%
  \FPpow\myTempC\myTempA{2}%
  \FPpow\myTempD\myTempB{2}%
  \FPadd\myTempC\myTempC\myTempD
  \FProot\myTempC\myTempC{2}% length of diagonal line in sp
  \FPdiv\myTempD\myTempB\myTempA
  \FParctan\myTempD\myTempD% angle of diagonal line in rad
  \smash{%
    \kern-\arraycolsep
    \rlap{%
      \lower
        \dimexpr
          \dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+\arrayrulewidth
        \relax
        \hbox{%
          \rotatebox[units=-6.283185,origin=br]{\myTempD}{%
            \rule{\myTempC sp}{\arrayrulewidth}%
          }%
        }%
    }%
  }%
}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\copy\MytempboxB}\\%
\cline{2-6}%
\copy\MytempboxA& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\%
\hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\%
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\%
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\%
\hline
\end{array}%
\]%
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Black box approach}%
\setbox\MytempboxA\hbox{\mbox{abc}}%
\setbox\MytempboxB\hbox{\mbox{def}}%
\[%
\begin{array}{@{}|r|*{5}{c}|}%
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{%
  \smash{%
    \kern-\arraycolsep
    \rlap{%
      \rule[{-\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname}]%
           {\dimexpr\wd\MytempboxA+2\arraycolsep\relax}%
           {%
             \dimexpr
               \dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+%
               \ht\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname
             \relax
           }%
    }%
  }%
}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\copy\MytempboxB}\\
\hline
\copy\MytempboxA& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\%
\hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\%
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\%
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\%
\hline
\end{array}%
\]%
\end{table}


\begin{table}%
\caption{Tangram puzzle approach}%
\[%
\setbox\MytempboxA\hbox{\mbox{abc}}%
\setbox\MytempboxB\hbox{\mbox{def}}%
\begin{array}{@{}|r|*{5}{c}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{%
  \edef\myTempA{%
    \number\numexpr\dimexpr\wd\MytempboxA+2\arraycolsep\relax\relax
  }%
  \edef\myTempB{%
    \number
    \numexpr
      \dimexpr\dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+%
              \ht\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+%
              \arrayrulewidth
      \relax
    \relax
  }%
  \FPpow\myTempC\myTempA{2}%
  \FPpow\myTempD\myTempB{2}%
  \FPadd\myTempC\myTempC\myTempD
  \FProot\myTempC\myTempC{2}% length of diagonal line in sp
  \FPdiv\myTempD\myTempB\myTempA
  \FParctan\myTempD\myTempD% angle of diagonal line in rad
  \smash{%
    \kern-\arraycolsep
    \rlap{%
      \lower
        \dimexpr
          \dp\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+\arrayrulewidth
        \relax
        \hbox{%
          \rotatebox[units=-6.283185,origin=br]{\myTempD}{%
            \rule{\myTempC sp}{\arrayrulewidth}%
          }%
        }%
    }%
  }%
}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\copy\MytempboxB}\\%
\copy\MytempboxA& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\%
\cline{2-6}%
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\%
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\%
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\%
\hline
\end{array}%
\]%
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{squares approach}%
\setbox\MytempboxA\hbox{\mbox{abc}}%
\setbox\MytempboxB\hbox{\mbox{def}}%
\[%
\begin{array}{@{}|r|*{5}{c}|}%
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\copy\MytempboxB}\\
\copy\MytempboxA& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\%
\cline{2-6}%
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\%
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\%
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\%
\hline
\end{array}%
\]%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And sometimes I use something like angle arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newbox\MytempboxA
\newbox\MytempboxB
\newbox\MytempboxC
\newcommand\Upbox[1]{%
  \lower\dimexpr-\ht\MytempboxA+\ht\MytempboxB\relax\hbox{#1}%
  %#1%
}%
\newcommand\leftbox[1]{%
  \hbox to\wd\MytempboxC{\hss#1\hss}\hbox to\wd\MytempboxB{\hfill}%
}%
\begin{document}

\begin{table}%
\caption{Angle arrow.}%
\setbox\MytempboxB=\hbox{\mbox{def}}%
\setbox\MytempboxC=\hbox{\mbox{abc}}%
\setbox\MytempboxA=\hbox{\lower\dp\MytempboxC\vbox{%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25cm, y=.25cm, inner sep=0pt]
    \draw[->,thin] (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right]{\copy\MytempboxB};
    \draw[->,thin] (0,0) -- (0,-1) node[below]{\copy\MytempboxC};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}}%
\[%
  \begin{array}{c|ccccc}%
  \copy\MytempboxA&\Upbox{1}&\Upbox{2}&\Upbox{3}&\Upbox{4}&\Upbox{5}\\%
  \hline
  \leftbox{1}& a & b & c & d & e\\%
  \leftbox{2} & f & g & h & i & j\\%
  \leftbox{3} & k & l & m & n & o\\%
  \end{array}%
\]
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{Another angle arrow.}%
\setbox\MytempboxB=\hbox{\mbox{def}}%
\setbox\MytempboxC=\hbox{\mbox{abc}}%
\[%
  \begin{array}{c@{}c|ccccc}%
  \smash{%
    \hbox{%
      \kern.5\wd\MytempboxC
      \lower.75\ht\MytempboxB
      \hbox{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25cm, y=.25cm, inner sep=0pt]
        \draw[->,thin] (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right]{};
        \draw[->,thin] (0,0) -- (0,-1) node[below]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }%
  }&\copy\MytempboxB&1&2&3&4&5\\%
  \copy\MytempboxC&&\\%
  \hline
  1&& a & b & c & d & e\\%
  2&& f & g & h & i & j\\%
  3&& k & l & m & n & o\\%
  \end{array}%
\]%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

You can also create the look and feel of coordinate system axes with horizontal and vertical lines of an array:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newbox\MytempboxA
\newbox\MytempboxB
\newbox\MytempboxC

\begin{document}

\begin{table}%
\caption{Coordinate axes approach.}%
\setbox\MytempboxC=\hbox{\mbox{abc}}%
\setbox\MytempboxB=\hbox{\mbox{def}}%
\setbox\MytempboxA\hbox{%
  \lower\arrayrulewidth\hbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25cm, y=.05cm, inner sep=0pt]%
  \draw[->,line width=\arrayrulewidth] (0,1) -- (1,1) node[right]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}%
\[%
  \begin{array}{c|cccccl}%
  &1&2&3&4&5&\\%
  \cline{1-6}%
  1& a & b & c & d & e&%
  \kern\dimexpr-\arraycolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth\relax\null
  \smash{%
      \lower\dimexpr-\ht\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+.75\arrayrulewidth+0pt\relax\copy\MytempboxA
      \lower\dimexpr-\ht\csname @arstrutbox\endcsname+0.5ex+.75\arrayrulewidth\relax\copy\MytempboxB
  }%
  \\%
  2 & f & g & h & i & j&\\%
  3 & k & l & m & n & o&\\%
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{}&%
  \multicolumn{6}{l}{%
    \kern\dimexpr-.5\wd\MytempboxC-\arraycolsep\relax\null
    \vbox{%
      \kern\dimexpr-.5\arrayrulewidth\relax\hbox{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25cm, y=.075cm, inner sep=0pt]%
        \draw[->,line width=\arrayrulewidth] (0,1) -- (0,-1) node[below]{\copy\MytempboxC};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \\%
  \end{array}%
\]
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many excellent answers has already been proposed. Actually, I ended up using a subscript and superscript based solution. The [negative spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67912/large-negative-spaces) required some fine-tuning.

The advantage of this approach is that it does not rely on external packages (and hence journal-friendly). The disadvantage is that two different font sizes are used, which is, perhaps, typographically discouraged.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Scripts.}
\[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
{}_{abc}\mkern-6mu\setminus\mkern-6mu{}^{def} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
2 & f & g & h & i & j\\
3 & k & l & m & n & o\\
\end{array}\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]