# construct a table's skeleton

Tags: tables

It is easy to find a way to draw a table in latex.

Unfortunately, I have a special type of a table that has a particular shape.

I have several problems to construct it in latex however for gaining help from *TexStackExchange* community I draw it by Microsoft word.

I just wish to obtain the table's skeleton and its elements are not important and can be any thing. I mean, the two top rows of table are more important than other rows.

How can construct the table's form as below shaped:

[image]

Comment: Does the table have to look like a maze of prison-cell windows, or are you open (pun intended) to giving the table an open and inviting look?

Comment: unfortunately I could not understand what you mean

Comment: Must your table absolutely feature 8 horizontal lines and 11 vertical lines? The fine grid of horizontal and vertical lines looks very much like a prison cell window...

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: The following might serve as a point to start from: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{10pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{10pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|Sc|Sc|}
\hline
\backslashbox{a}{b} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{c}\\
\hline
d & e & f\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339535/what-to-put-into-the-intersection-of-the-row-column-labels-of-a-table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two ways to construct the table.

- The upper table strives for an open "look": no vertical lines and few but well-spaced horizontal lines. The reader's eyes are invited into the table and are free to roam around and take in all the information.
- The lower table has an extremely closed look, mainly because of the overabundance of horizontal (8) and vertical (11) lines. It's not easy to move one's eyes from cell to cell.

It's up to you to decide which "look" works for you -- and, hopefully, for your readers as well. (Speaking for myself, I have a strong preference for the open look...)

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Choose page parameters suitably:
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\[
%% First, the open "look"
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.25}
\begin{array}{@{} l *{9}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^*(m)}     & t^*(m)     
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{**}(m)}  & t^{**}(m)  
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{***}(m)} & t^{***}(m) \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
m & \frac{m-1}{m} & 2-\frac{m-1}{m} & m\pi 
  & \frac{m-3}{m} & 2-\frac{m-3}{m} & m\pi 
  & \frac{m-5}{m} & 2-\frac{m-5}{m} & m\pi \\
\midrule
1 & 0           & \frac{2}{1}=2 &  \pi & & & & & & \\
2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2}   & 2\pi & & & & & & \\
3 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{3}{4}   & 3\pi & & & & & & \\
4 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{5}{4}   & 4\pi & & & & & & \\
5 & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{6}{5}   & 5\pi & & & & 0 & \frac{10}{5}=2 & 5\pi \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

\[
%% Second, the very closed "look"
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{array}{| l | *{9}{>{\displaystyle}c|} }
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{J^*(m)}     & t^*(m)     
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{J^{**}(m)}  & t^{**}(m)  
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{J^{***}(m)} & t^{***}(m) \\
\hline
m & \frac{m-1}{m} & 2-\frac{m-1}{m} & m\pi 
  & \frac{m-3}{m} & 2-\frac{m-3}{m} & m\pi 
  & \frac{m-5}{m} & 2-\frac{m-5}{m} & m\pi \\
\hline
1 & 0           & \frac{2}{1}=2 &  \pi & & & & & & \\
\hline
2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2}   & 2\pi & & & & & & \\
\hline
3 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{3}{4}   & 3\pi & & & & & & \\
\hline
4 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{5}{4}   & 4\pi & & & & & & \\
\hline
5 & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{6}{5}   & 5\pi & & & & 0 & \frac{10}{5}=2 & 5\pi\\
\hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address @Sveinung's follow-up comment regarding desirable typographic features of the table: I fully agree with your observation that the second header row is currently too prominent, visually speaking; this is the case for both the "open" and the "closed" version. I didn't raise this issue in my initial answer because I had no idea if the OP's code, which contains lots of fraction terms, is for real or is meant as a mock-up. (One reason to believe it's mainly mock-up is that the information in columns 4, 7, and 10 is repeated verbatim.)

Assuming the fractional expressions in the second header row are for real, I can think of (at least!) 3 different, not mutually exclusive, approaches to improving the typography: (i) use a smaller font size for the entries in the second header  row; (ii) switch from display-style to text-style fractions by using `\tfrac` instead of `\frac`; and (iii) use inline math notation; e.g., replace `\frac{m-1}{m}` and `2-\frac{m-1}{m}` with `1-1/m` and `1+1/m`, respectively.

The third approach is implemented in the following table. Note that I've introduced inline-fraction notation not only in the header but in the body of the table as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\[
%% Third, a much more compact (but still "open") look
\begin{array}{@{} l *{9}{c} @{}}
\toprule
m & \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^*(m)}     & t^*(m)
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{**}(m)}  & t^{**}(m)
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{***}(m)} & t^{***}(m) \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
& 1-1/m & 1+1/m & m\pi
& 1-3/m & 1+3/m & m\pi
& 1-5/m & 1+5/m & m\pi \\
\midrule
1 & 0   & 2   &  \pi \\
2 & 1/2 & 3/2 & 2\pi \\
3 & 2/3 & 4/3 & 3\pi & 0   & 2   & 3\pi \\
4 & 3/4 & 5/4 & 4\pi & 1/4 & 7/4 & 4\pi \\
5 & 4/5 & 6/5 & 5\pi & 2/5 & 8/5 & 5\pi & 0 & 2 & 5\pi \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a follow-up question posted by the OP: To typeset the tabular material centered at the top of a page in a two-column document, you should encase all material from `\[` to `\]` in a `table*` environment:

```
% ...
\begin{table*} % <-- new
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l *{9}{c} @{}}
\toprule
% (body of table)
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{table*} % <-- new

% ... (remainder of document)
```

Comment: Wonderful and Excellent!!!

Comment: I think the "open look" is very better...

Comment: @Irreversible -- I'm glad we agree. :-)

Comment: @Mico In my opinion, and based on some typography text books, the heading should be typeset with smaller fontsize. As it is now, I feel it is too much air. Also, the heading for columns 4, 7 and 10 would look better if aligned at the bottom of the head row (on two lines)

Comment: @Mico I'm glad we agree. :-) (Intentional citation theft :=)

Comment: @Sveinung - I fully agree with your point that the second header row, in particular, is given far too much visual prominence. Please see the addendum I just posted, in which I address this issue, mainly by making the entire table much more compact than was the case initially.

Comment: @Mico Really nice and readable. The textbook I read, was from the mid-fifties and heavily influenced by German typhography.  The philosophy behind reduced font size of the heading is probably that the figures in the column is the most important information, and that a dominant heading (bold, colour, text heavy rules) take the focus from what is important.

Comment: @Mico, besides so much thanks to you for your help I have a question: If we  insert the code in a two-column text file and if we wish to have the table in the top -center of a page, this code disagrees to us. Such a code constructs the table wherever is inserted and extends to other column. How can I overcome this problem?!!!

Comment: @Irreversible - You could encase everything between `\[` and `\]` in a `table*` environment.

Comment: I thing I have to change `array` into `tabular` is it correct?

Comment: @Irreversible - Not if you keep the `array` inside `\[` and `\]` instructions.

Comment: Thanks, I should try...

Comment: I modified the first line into `\[
\begin{table*}
\begin{array}{@{} l *{9}{c} @{}}
\toprule` and corresponding the end lines but I enforced with some problems

Comment: @Irreversible - No! It must be `\begin{table*} \[ ... \] \end{table*}. Basically, what was previously a standalone display-math environment -- *including* `\[` and `\]` -- must be encased in a `table*` environment.

Comment: Thank you so much.....so sorry for my mistake .....

Comment: So sorry for interrupting you. I have so much tried with \centering after \\begin{table} or \begin{center} before that, for putting the table in the center of the page's top but I could not reach to my goal.

Comment: @Irreversible -- I suggested `\begin{table*}` and `\end{table*}`, ***not*** `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}`. As long as you use `\[` and `\]` (as is done in the code above!), there should be *no need whatsoever* for a `\centering` instruction or a `center` environment. If, for some reason, you prefer not to use `\[` and `\]`, there's not really any further role for me to play.

Comment: @Irreversible - Please see the addendum I just posted at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Irreversible -- By the way, one should never, ever place a `table` or `table*` environment inside a `center` environment. For sure, I did ***not*** suggest that you do so.

Comment: @Mico, thank you so much. I had made use of table* and  for a short description , I wrote table. You are completely right. Thank you so much